# Is it possible to deploy a .NET 4 MVC3 Asp.Net to Azure Websites now?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database

I am using MVC3/.net4/c#/razor/EF4.1/SQL Server 2008sp2/Membership services.

I am trying to deploy this to an Azure Website.

It appears I can only deploy a .net 3.5 or .net 4.5 web application which is a slight pain for me, as I have 3rd party dlls which are written in 4.0

Seems quite strange that .net 4.0 is missing from websites.

Reconfiguring my site to 4.5 is not trivial since it uses these 3rd party dlls.

Any thoughts on this please.

Thank you in advance.

P.s Also it appears that deployment of ASP.Net Membership Services is probelematic.

Comment: A 4.5 site should be able to use dll's written in 4.0. What issues are you getting when you upgrade the site to 4.5?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I was getting some strange build errors, with "errors 0 of 8", with  none listed, but clearly something afoot as the build terminated too quickly. So are you saying that all my 3rd party V4 assemblies should be fine. Perhaps the cause is elsewhere. I have changed the build version to 4.5 for both web project and model project(EF classes). Out of interest would a V4 built solution run ontop of the v4.5 framework without any rebuilds? Feels like a stupid question, but I thought I should ask it.

Comment: I have upgraded many sites to 4.5 and more recently 4.5.1 which use dll's ranging back to 3 and have experienced no issues. It's possible for 3rd party dll's to experience issues when used from a site/project of a much higher version, but I've not experienced it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never heard of such a problem with azure websites. i have myself deployed several sites that both contained dll's build with 2.0, 3.5, 4.0 without any problems.

I think your problem is caused by something else and if you cant get it to work then post the build error :)

Comment: In the end I deployed my .net 4 compiled web application to see if it would work in Azure on 4.5 and it did, to my surprise, well so far so good. This includes the Model project and main web project as .net4. Just waiting for the next gotcha!!! Thanks